# How to edit embedded iframes?

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, embed

I seek to embed a [Desmos page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/foa97c6fbc) onto my website, having all other display elements removed but the graph itself and 'sliders'. In the linked example, I'd like to keep only the `a = ...` slider, and move it to the bottom of the page; should look like
[image]

How can this be accomplished? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe will show the entire site, so that might not be the right solution for you.  You could try masking the rest of the content by putting the iframe inside of another element, but that might not be what you are looking for either. The website does offer and export to image feature. Could that work for your needs?

Comment: Works sometimes, yes - if an iframe won't do it, are there other methods of embedding web content w/ edit capabilities?

Comment: It all really depends on the format the content is in, but in the case of Desmos, I would expect not.  It seems like you're limited to their supplied image export and embed options.